# Node.js-Web-App in Azure won't show anything

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js

I am trying to deploy my vue project on azure and used this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode
I skipped the step with creating the myExpressApp because I wanted to deploy my own project.
My problem is the hosted URL is not showing anything. Instead I get an error, because the website can't find main.ts:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT8Af.png)

But as you can see the file exists in the app service: [Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiVNg.png)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

I tried to deploy my application with this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode and expected it to run properly.

Comment: can you share the code which you have tried and deployment doing in linux or windows web app?

Comment: It's a big project. I can't show the whole code. Which part do you want exactly?
I used windows web app

Comment: What is your exact requirement after deploying the vue project into web app your getting nothing while hosting the web app URL right?

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to create a `Vue.js` and deploy it to the Web app Instead of this line change it to

- Check the below steps to create `Vue.js` and deploy it to the Azure app service
- Install `npm install -g @vue/cli`

**Create a new Vue project:**

`vue create your-project-name`

[image]

- Navigate to the project file location and build the application.

[image]

- `npm run build` to build the application.

[image]

- Run the development server with `npm run serve`.

[image]

**Local:**

[image]

- Select and deploy only the `dist` folder.
- I have  Followed the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode#configure-the-app-service-app-and-deploy-code) which you have shared to the Deploy from VSCode.

**Deployment Status:**

[image]

**Deployed Output:**

[image]